# How add rollupNodePolyFill to electron.vite.configs

Tags: electron, vite

I need excute 'twilio-client' on electron project

```
import Twilio from 'twilio-client';

// this line broken when run electron-vite preview or builded app version
const device = new Twilio.Device();

device.setup('xyls', {
  debug: true
});

console.log(device);
```

When I run my app with electron-vite preview or after build, I got an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "events"

This also happened when it was executed:
electron-vite dev --watch

I added nodePolifill plugins now it works in dev mode, but on preview or build doesn't

The plugin 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills' doesn't works on build.rollupOptions.plugins

I need help

My electron.vite.configs.ts:

```
import { resolve, normalize, dirname } from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'electron-vite'

import injectProcessEnvPlugin from 'rollup-plugin-inject-process-env'
import tsconfigPathsPlugin from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'
import reactPlugin from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill'
import { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill'
import rollupNodePolyFill from "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills";

import { main, resources } from './package.json'

const [nodeModules, devFolder] = normalize(dirname(main)).split(/\/|\\/g)
const devPath = [nodeModules, devFolder].join('/')

const tsconfigPaths = tsconfigPathsPlugin({
  projects: [resolve('tsconfig.json')],
})

export default defineConfig({
  main: {
    plugins: [tsconfigPaths],

    build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        input: {
          index: resolve('src/main/index.ts'),
        },

        output: {
          dir: resolve(devPath, 'main'),
        },
      },
    },
  },

  preload: {
    plugins: [tsconfigPaths],

    build: {
      outDir: resolve(devPath, 'preload'),
    },
  },

  renderer: {
    define: {
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      'process.platform': JSON.stringify(process.platform),
    },

    server: {
      port: 4927,
    },

    publicDir: resolve(resources, 'public'),

    plugins: [
      tsconfigPaths,
      reactPlugin(),
    ],

    resolve: {
      alias: {
        util: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/util',
        sys: 'util',
        stream: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/stream',
        path: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/path',
        querystring: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/qs',
        punycode: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/punycode',
        url: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/url',
        string_decoder: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/string-decoder',
        http: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http',
        https: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http',
        os: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/os',
        assert: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/assert',
        constants: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/constants',
        _stream_duplex: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/duplex',
        _stream_passthrough: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/passthrough',
        _stream_readable: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/readable',
        _stream_writable: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/writable',
        _stream_transform: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/transform',
        timers: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/timers',
        console: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/console',
        vm: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/vm',
        zlib: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/zlib',
        tty: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/tty',
        domain: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/domain',
        events: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/events',
        buffer: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/buffer-es6', // add buffer
        process: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/process-es6', // add process
      }
    },

    optimizeDeps: {
      esbuildOptions: {
        // Node.js global to browser globalThis
        define: {
          global: 'globalThis'
        },
        // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
        plugins: [
          NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
            process: true,
            buffer: true,
          }),
          NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin(),
        ]
      }
    },

    worker: {
      format: "es",
    },

    build: {
      outDir: resolve(devPath, 'renderer'),

      rollupOptions: {
        plugins: [
          injectProcessEnvPlugin({
            NODE_ENV: 'production',
            platform: process.platform,
          }),
          rollupNodePolyFill() //this line doesn't works
        ],

        input: {
          index: resolve('src/renderer/index.html'),
        },

        output: {
          format: "esm",
          dir: resolve(devPath, 'renderer'),
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

and the is my project repostitory:

[https://github.com/caioregatieri/app-electron](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I tried add many polyfills, add twilio import on preload and export to render with

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('Twilio', Twilio)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with:

electron.vite.config.ts

```
    build: {
      outDir: resolve(devPath, 'renderer'),

      rollupOptions: {
        plugins: [
          injectProcessEnvPlugin({
            NODE_ENV: 'production',
            platform: process.platform,
          }),
          rollupNodePolyFill,
        ],
      },
    },
```

and this:

index.html

```
    <script>
      global = globalThis;
    </script>
```